# Display keyboard input on screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, on-screen-keyboard

I'm doing demos which involve demonstrating keyboard shortcuts for various programs (in Windows 7). I'd like for the audience to be able to see what I entered without my having to say every key I'm pressing.

How can I display the last few key combinations I've entered?

Comment: Are you on Windows or OS X?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [KeyJedi](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/05/29/key-jedi-1-03-renamed-from-shortwatcher.aspx).

Comment: Had to follow this blog post to get it to run on x64, but it works great. http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/KeyboardJediOnVistaX64.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you're on OS X, I recommend [Screenium](http://www.synium.de/products/screenium/index.html).